# Export JavaScript Object without Node.js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to export an Object from a .js file to another one.
Actually I found many bits of help but with Node.js, and I'm not using it.

Do you think it's possible to do it without Node.js?

I've tried something :

```
//file1.js
var MyObject = {
property: value
};

export{MyObject};

//file2.js
import MyObject from 'file2.js';
```

This code gives me some errors :

- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

EDIT : I've found another way to do what I was looking for without using the export method, thanks to the helpers !

Comment: Node.js supports ES6 modules with the experimental flag `--experimental-modules`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//file1.js
var MyObject = {
property: value
};

module.exports= MyObject;

//file2.js
var <Anyname>= require(<path>);
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, but I've found an other way to do what I was look for that doesn't need to export it, thanks for the help anyway !